# how convert date(02/07/2012) to Tuesday, Febraury 7, 2012

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Can any one please help me how to convert date(02/07/2012) to Tuesday, Febraury 7, 2012.
And how can i relate it to datepicker.

OR

is there any date picker which provides date like Tuesday, Febraury 7, 2012 ,when user selects date from datepicker.And how can i add next and previous buttons to the date picker.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js">         
</script>
<script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();


        });
   </script>
</head>  
<body>  
    <div>

    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

    </div>
</body>

<script>

$("#datepicker").click(function(){
    var date = $("#datepicker").val();

    var date_obj = new Date(date);

    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

    var date_str = days[date_obj.getMonth()] + ", " + months[date_obj.getMonth()] + " " + date_obj.getDate() + ", " + (1900+date_obj.getYear());

    alert(date_str);
});
</script>
</html>
```

I tried like this but its just alert before date picker.
Which event I have to use here?
Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language are you using? You listed two in your tags and didn't specify which in your post.

Comment: Php and Javasript are very different languages

Comment: I am using javascript on client side and php on server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can create a new `Date` using the string `02/07/2012`. The `Date` object will then identify the day of the week for you. From there you can use `Array`s to identify the English-language month and day.

Example:

```
var date = "02/07/2012";
var date_obj = new Date(date);

var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

var date_str = days[date_obj.getMonth()] + ", " + months[date_obj.getMonth()] + " " + date_obj.getDate() + ", " + (1900+date_obj.getYear());

document.write(date_str);
```

An another approach is to split the `02/07/2012` using `/` as a delimiter. This will give you an array `[02, 07, 2012]`, which can be used to pull elements from the months array.

Using that method you will need an alternative method to identify the day of the week and you will need to strip the leading zero from "07".

Comment: Thanks for your solution.How can I add next and previous buttons to the input box which holds datepicker value.

Answer (score 1):

datepicker is very easy to use:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
            });
            </script>
    </head>  
<body>  
        <div>

        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

        </div>
</body>
    </html>
```